# VIM script sort array of strings based on numbers with in the strings

Tags: arrays, function, sorting, vim

I am trying to sort and array in VIM script containing strings each string might have a number in it.
I wish to sort the array according to the number (and trailing char).
The array is:

```
let arr = ["FUNC10B", "FUNC8", "FUNC2", "FUNC10A"]
```

The sorted array should come out as:

```
["FUNC2", "FUNC8", "FUNC10A", "FUNC10B"]
```

I was hoping that `sort(arr, 'n')` will do the big part I need but for some reason it doesn't.
I want to run it by my own function: `sort(arr, 'my_sort')`.
Can someone help me with this function! `my_sort...` ?
Thanks.

Comment: it think would help if you will ask this question more general way and tagged it by language not by editor. The are some people that don't write scripts in vim but can solve this sorting issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this is a script I want to run in a vimscript, so it is not just the editor, but the actual language I want to be using.

Answer (score 1):

OK , so after some trail and error I managed to get the below function to do what I want.
If anyone has a better way to do this , I will be more than happy to hear.
I am not sure why the second if didn't work with a simple `match` command , I worked around it with `matchlist` and `len` commands.
Thanks

```
function! My_Sort(i1, i2)
    let l:score1 = 0 
    let l:score2 = 0
    if match(a:i1 , '\d\+')
        let l:score1 = matchlist(a:i1 , '\(\d\+\)')[0]
        let chrs = matchlist(a:i1 , l:score1.'\(\S\)')
        if len(chrs)
            let chr = chrs[0]
            let chr = char2nr(substitute(chr , l:score1 , '' , 'g'))
            let l:score1 = l:score1 + chr
        endif
    endif
    if match(a:i2 , '\d\+')
        let l:score2 = matchlist(a:i2 , '\(\d\+\)')[0]
        let chrs = matchlist(a:i2 , l:score2.'\(\S\)')
        if len(chrs)
            let chr = chrs[0]
            let chr = char2nr(substitute(chr , l:score2 , '' , 'g'))
            let l:score2 = l:score2 + chr
        endif
    endif
   return l:score1 == l:score2 ? 0 : l:score1 > l:score2 ? 1 : -1       
endfunction
```